# Why does my account keeps getting locked? What does the log Event 4648 means?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, lock

I have this problem I just cant seem to find the source.
My AD account keeps getting locked.
Using lockout status and looking at the netlogon log i figured out which PC it is.
I know which process is locking me: spoolsv.exe.
Spoolsv.exe is running as system not as me but I get this log entry.

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          3/28/2014 9:45:01 AM
Event ID:      4648
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      computer.MYDOMAIN.NET
Description:
A logon was attempted using explicit credentials.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x79F5
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Account Whose Credentials Were Used:
    Account Name:       accountbeinglocked@mydomain.net
    Account Domain:     
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Target Server:
    Target Server Name: FILESERVER.MYDOMAIN.NET
    Additional Information: FILESERVER.MYDOMAIN.NET

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x544
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe

Network Information:
    Network Address:    -
    Port:           -

This event is generated when a process attempts to log on an account by explicitly specifying that account’s credentials.  This most commonly occurs in batch-type configurations such as scheduled tasks, or when using the RUNAS command.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4648</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12544</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-28T13:45:01.502850800Z" />
    <EventRecordID>308669</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="784" ThreadID="5280" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>computer.MYDOMAIN.NET</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x79f5</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonGuid">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">accountbeinglocked@mydomain.net</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="TargetLogonGuid">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetServerName">FILESERVER.MYDOMAIN.NET</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetInfo">FILESERVER.MYDOMAIN.NET</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x544</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessName">C:\Windows\System32\spoolsv.exe</Data>
    <Data Name="IpAddress">-</Data>
    <Data Name="IpPort">-</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I have no idea at all how to fix this. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you logged into "computer.MYDOMAIN.NET" when this happens? Any services on the computer set to login using the "accountbeinglocked@mydomain.net"?  Have you scanned for Malware yet?

Comment: No I'm not, someone else is logged in as another AD user, no services set to login as user "accountbeingblocked@mydomain.net". Yes i did scan for malware. with multiple scanner and even using a boot disk to check for rootkit. The printer spooler is started as SERVICE.

Comment: 4648 A logon was attempted using explicit credentials. See here: https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4648   This event is logged anytime an auth request is made using credentials that are different from the login used on the local machine.

Comment: I found that information too, my question is why is spoolsv.exe using those credentials. And how do i tell it not to use them anymore?

Comment: That is the print spooler. If you've printed using your AD credentials (say to a network printer on the domain), then spoolsv.exe will be using those credentials in order to complete your print request.

Comment: This is a possibility I sometime sit at a user desk and use my credential to access other network ressource and will enter my credential. How do I stop the print spooler from using my credential anymore? I tried everything I could think of. Disconnected share removed all shared printer. And if those printer are not used I dont get locked but the user needs those printer share how do i make sure when I add those printer back it is not using my credential?

Comment: Worth a try: Remove all mapped network shares, relog into the PC, then map them again.

Comment: I suspect it is an e.g. HP or Brother driver/service attempting to do {magic} like upsell ink or connect to so-called cloud printing etc.

Comment: Done All That did not work

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly from cached credentials used to access a network resource (as noted in comments)

You can remove the authenticated credentials from:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts

click the username 
1.To the left you will see Manage your credentials.  From that select the share/resource name and remove

You will need to find any and all systems that use the credentials.

Comment: I have already emptied mine and the user that locks me Credential Vault Doesnt fix the problem

Comment: How do I do that. And as you have seen from the event error i know that spoolsv.exe is contacting the fileserver with my credential. but how why it calls it using my credential?

Comment: Have you cleared it from all possible workstations? It would likely be a shared printer you accessed from a computer other than your usual one.  Any chance you run a virtual machine somewhere?  Have seen a copied VM cause this

Comment: I was able to really identify that station as the problem by correlating my lockout with printing something or even just looking at printer properties. I dont get lock if that PC is not running. There is no VM on any PC here and I run some but they were all shut down. The fix will be to reinstall everything on that PC that should fix it but i'd rather figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
psexec -i -s -d cmd
cmdkey /list
```

This shows if system account has any credentials stored, remove them with `cmdkey /delete:target`

e.g.

```
cmdkey /delete:192.168.1.2
```

Comment: This is a great command. I did not know about it. Unfortunately it did not fix my issue and only replicate what you see by looking in the Credential Vault.